# Make a check for some numbers

Tags: groovy

I've got a code:

```
Scanner scanner = new Scanner(System.in);
System.out.print("Enter your ID: ");
int U_id = scanner.nextInt();
println("$U_id")

import java.util.regex.Pattern

try {
    String U_id_str = "$U_id"

    Pattern pattern = Pattern.compile(/^([0-9]{5})([0-9]{3})([0-9])([0-9])$/)

    def (_, birthNum, pNum, gend, kNum) = (U_id_str =~ pattern)[0]
    println "birthNum = ${birthNum}, pNum = ${pNum}, ${gend}, Key number - ${kNum}"

} catch (IndexOutOfBoundsException ex) {
    println "Input string does not match regular expression..."
}
```

I need to male a check. If 'gend' is even then gend_w = "man", else gend_w = "woman". And I need to count birthNum_w. BirthNum_w = number of days from 01.01.1900. For example 40176 says that date is 01.01.2010

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can check `gend` is an odd by checking the remainder when dividing by 2

```
boolean isOdd = gend % 2
```

For the days since 1900, you can use:

```
import java.time.LocalDate

LocalDate dob = LocalDate.of(1900, 1, 1).plusDays(40176)
```

which gives you 2009-12-31...  Did you miss a leap year in your calculations?